# SAF - Invalid Uri error when copying file from private app folder to authorized SAF folder

Tags: android, directory, nullpointerexception, file-copying, storage-access-framework

My Android has to copy a file from private app folder to a SAF location that was previously granted permissions and authorized.
The code is:

```
static boolean copyDocumentFileToTargetFolderWithNewName(Activity activity, String docUri,String targetFolderUri,String newName)
{
    deleteIfExisting(activity,Uri.parse(targetFolderUri),newName);
    ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    boolean result=false;
    Log.d("copy",docUri+" "+targetFolderUri+" "+newName);
    Log.d("doc exists",String.valueOf(fileExists(activity,docUri)));  //error here
    try {
        DocumentsContract.copyDocument(resolver,Uri.parse(docUri),Uri.parse(targetFolderUri));//or error here
        DocumentsContract.renameDocument(resolver,Uri.parse(docUri),newName);
        result=true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        result=false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and

```
static public boolean fileExists(Activity activity,String fileUriString)
{
    ContentResolver contentResolver;
    contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    String parentFolderUriString=StringUtils.fromLastSlashLeft(fileUriString);
    String fileName=StringUtils.fromLastSlashRight(fileUriString);
    Uri parentFolderUri=Uri.parse(parentFolderUriString);
    boolean exists;
    DocumentFile docFile=DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity,parentFolderUri).findFile(fileName); //error here
    exists= (null!=docFile);
    return exists;
}
```

(with some self-explanatory string utility calls)

Here the result from the Log.d() line

```
D/copy: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myappname.app/folder/subfolder/file.txt content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2FSAFfolder/newname.txt
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myappname.app/folder/subfolder/file.txt
```

at

```
DocumentFile docFile=DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity,parentFolderUri).findFile(fileName);
```

in the second method

or, when Log.d() is commented,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
```

at this line:

```
DocumentsContract.copyDocument(resolver,Uri.parse(docUri),Uri.parse(targetFolderUri));
```

in the first method.
What's wrong with my code? Aren't private folder uris authorized? How to authorize them?

Answer (score 1):

> What's wrong with my code?

Neither `docUri` nor `parentFolderUri` is a document `Uri`. They are `Uri` values that you created using `Uri.fromFile()` or something. You can tell because they have the `file` scheme.

With regards to your immediate crash, `fromTreeUri()` requires a document `Uri`. Use `fromFile()` for `file` `Uri` values.

Once you get past that, I expect that you will crash in your `copyDocument()` call. That's what I originally thought the problem was, until I re-read your question. You are trying to copy a non-document `Uri` (`docUri`), and [the JavaDocs for `copyDocument()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract?hl=en#copyDocument(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri)) state that the first parameter needs to be a document `Uri`:

> document with Document#FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY This value must never be null.

When `DocumentsContract` refers to a `Uri` as a "document", it means a `Uri` obtained through `DocumentsContract` itself. That would include a `Uri` obtained through `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or a `Uri` obtained through a tree `DocumentFile`. However, that will not cover:

- A `Uri` created by `Uri.fromFile()`
- A `Uri` from `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`
- A `Uri` created by `Uri.parse()` from an `http` or `https` URL
- Etc.

> Aren't private folder uris authorized?

It is not a question of "authorization". `fromTreeUri()` expects a document `Uri`. `copyDocument()` expects a document `Uri`. You cannot use them with non-document `Uri` values, that's all.

Comment: So, Do I have to send an Intent or there is a way to convert file:/// uris to suitably authorized content:/// form?

Comment: @P5music: I don't know of any way to accomplish that. Note that you can copy your file to a document using ordinary Java file I/O, using `ContentResolver` and its `openOutputStream()` method to get an `OutputStream` to write the bytes to. AFAIK `copyDocument()` is there in case both documents are handled by the same provider and there happen to be "shortcuts" that don't involve an actual local copy operation. For example, copying from one Google Drive document to another probably just involves a network call to the Google server, and the actual copy is made there.

Comment: Yes, I think there are multiple ways. Maybe also passing an Intent. I have to check. I can also create my own copy method using OutpuStream.